# When I add the "formControlName" field in my angular code, the entire element disappears

Tags: html, css, angular

I've seen similar questions but they're about the content and not the entire element.
My code is the following:

```
<mat-form-field class="box-field"
[ngStyle]="{'background': 'url(assets/img/user.png) no-repeat padding-box'}">
<mat-label>Username</mat-label>
 <input matInput name="username" formControlName="username" autocomplete="off">
<mat-icon class="icon-display"></mat-icon>
 </mat-form-field>
```

The ts file is the following:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  
  constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private _loginFormBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log();
        // reset alerts on submit
        //this.alertService.clear();

        //this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.loginForm.get('username').value, this.loginForm.get('password').value)
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
            console.log(data)}
            );
  }

}
```

Without the "formControlName" field the page loads like this:
[og-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Deg0z.png)

When I add the field, it loads like this:
[broken-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfmGG.png)

And only when I click on it, it appears again like this:
[on-click-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypg61.png)

Anyone knows why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you add this name in formGroup part in controller?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzamil I hadn't before, but even now that I did the behaviour is the same.

Comment: can you post the whole code, ts file and html

Comment: can you post the ts file ?

Comment: yes please post controller code and view code here

Answer (score 0):

So after I added the following snippet in my constructor it worked:

```
      this.loginForm = this._loginFormBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
      })
```

Still not sure what exactly happened before.